# Global variables in JavaScript with multiple files

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a file called index.php. With script tags, it references index.js.

I also have a file called payment.php. With script tags, it references payment.js.

I need to set a variable called seatSelected in index.js and then use it in payment.js. However, I do not want to reference index.js in payment.php.

I have tried to make a file called globals.js, reference it in index.php before index.js containing the following:

```
var selectedSeat;

function setSelectedSeat(seat){
    selectedSeat = seat;
}

function getSelectedSeat(){
    return selectedSeat;
}
```

And setting the value in index.js with:

```
setSelectedSeat("test");
```

Receiving it in payment.js with (referencing globals.ks in payment.php above payment.js):

```
alert(getSelectedSeat());
```

But it alerts 'undefined'. Am I doing something wrong? How can I reference this variable without referencing the file it is changed in?

Comment: where is seat defined?

Comment: seat was just a placeholder. I can send setSelectedSeat('test'); and it's still undefined. edited.

Comment: What does `payment.php` have to do with `index.php`? If the two scripts are not loaded into the same page at the same time, you won't be able to make crossreferences. Instead you need to store that value which you want to persist somewhere (server, cookie, localStorage, whatever) and load it from the other page.

Comment: How do you transit from index.php to payment.php... does your page gets refreshed during the transition? Also, are you wanting the selectedSeats to retain the value that the user selected in index.php in payment.php?

Comment: Ah, duh. The page changes with window.location. Of course it wouldn't transfer over. What's the best way to store this data? Cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access variables created from another page.

You could use `localStorage` with `cookies` as fallback.

```
function setSelectedSeat(seat){
    if(localStorage) {
      localStorage['selectedSeat'] = JSON.stringify(seat);
    }
    else {
      //add code to store seat in cookie
    }
}

function getSelectedSeat(){
    if(localStorage) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage['selectedSeat']);
    }
    else {
      //add code to retrive seat in cookie
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to serialize/deserialize the values - currently it only works for strings

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to persist the state of variables while transitioning from one page to another and your application seems to have data that would require session expiry, I suggest you use `sessionstorage`. With help of polyfills you can give `sessionstorage` support till `IE6` browser.

### Benefit of using `SessionStorage` over `LocalStorage`

- Session Storage persists the data only for a particular tab/window and the data is lost when the tab/window is closed.
- As the data gets expired automatically you don't need to worry about session expiring.
- You can expire your session at your will as well.
- The data persists on page refreshes.

But Remember with `sessionstorage` you can only store strings `key-value` pattern. And you need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` method to store your complex objects in browser memory.

Here you can find a list of polyfills that you can use to provide the support of sessionstorage in non supporting browsers : https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-storage-localstorage-and-sessionstorage

Also you can read the following article to understand `sessionstorage` and `localstorage` in a better way: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html